# Implementing role based security in EJB, JPA, JSF application in JBoss

Tags: jpa, jboss, persistence.xml

We are planning an application using EJB, JPA (persistence) & JSF (Primefaces) architecture on JBoss EAP 6.4. The way data is stored in the database or the nature of the application is, we need to use/implement Role Based Security from application layer as well. We are able to create multiple DB Connection pools (to the same DB instance) in JBoss container and each JNDI is associated with a specific DB role. In other words, if I use JNDI_Role1 connection then it will return rows from DB table according to Role1 vs if I use JNDI_Role2 connection then it will return rows from the same DB table according to Role2 which would be different then Role1 and so on. We have 4 different roles created in DB, so 4 different JNDI connection pools in JBoss container.

Now, can I implement this in my Persistence layer? If yes, how can I do that? Should I create multiple EntityManager instances tied to each connection pool/JNDI? Any suggestions with some sample code would be really appreciated!!

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

There are some links which describes role based security: See the links

[1]https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.4/html-single/Security_Guide/index.html

[2]https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.4/html-single/how_to_configure_server_security/

[3]https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.4/html-single/security_architecture/#role_based_access_control